# How do I generate custom TextFields from an array of strings, each with its own edit/delete controls?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My IOS application has a form-builder for users. Users can create a form, add questions to it, and change question types, including Text Response, Multiple Choice, and Checkbox. For the Multiple Choice and Checkbox types, users must provide between 2-5 options.

In my `QuestionManager` (view model), I'm storing these options as an array of strings. In the view, I'm generating `OptionCell`s using a `ForEach` loop. Each `OptionCell` has a `TextField` and control functions to delete, edit and confirm each option. The issue is that I'm unsure about my approach because there are a few bugs that I think are due to the way I've set this up.

For example, which is really the only issue, I have a `@State var isEditing: Bool` variable in the `OptionCell` that is not being updated, which I believe has something do with the way I've declared the `@Published var options: [String]` in the `QuestionManager`. Or it might have something to do with the `@State var option: String` in the `OptionCell`. (I tried setting this up as `@Binding`, but for some reason that would not work.) But none of this makes sense to me since the `isEditing` variable is set up to update when the View is tapped, though I've narrowed the problem down to what I'm most uncertain about and I believe it is somehow related to what I described above. Any suggestions?

```
struct OptionCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var manager: QuestionManager
    @State var option: String
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false
    var optIndex: Int
    
    init(_ manager: QuestionManager, option: String) {
        self.manager = manager
        self.option = option
        self.optIndex = manager.options!.firstIndex(of: option)!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            MyCustomTextField(text: $option)
                .keyboardType(.default)
                .onTapGesture {
                    option = ""
                    isEditing = true // The main issue -> Isnt updating the view
                }

            // ActionIcon is just a Button with a SFLabels string input
            ActionIcon(isEditing ? "checkmark" : "xmark", size: 10) { // No changes are recognized
                isEditing ? saveOption() : deleteOption()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
    
    func saveOption() {
        if option == "" {
            manager.error = "An option must not be empty"
        } else {
            manager.options![optIndex] = option
            isEditing = false
        }
    }
    
    func deleteOption() {
        if manager.options!.count == 2 {
            manager.error = "You must have at least two options"
        } else {
            manager.deleteOption(option: option)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    @ObservedObject var manager: QuestionManager
    
    init(_ manager: QuestionManager) { self.manager = manager }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyCustomViewWrapper { 
            // ^ Reskins the background, adds padding, etc.

                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ConstantTitledTextField("Type", manager.type.rawValue)
                        // ^ Reskinned TextField
                            .overlay {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    self.changeTypeMenu
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                .padding(.top, 30)
                            }
                        TitledTextField("Prompt", $manager.prompt)
                        // ^ Another reskinned TextField
                            .keyboardType(.default)
                            .onTapGesture { manager.prompt = "" }
                        
                        MyCustomDivider()
                        
                        if manager.options != nil {
                            self.optionsSection
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $manager.error.isNotNil()) {
                MyCustomAlert(manager.error!) { manager.error = nil }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                MyCustomButton("Save") { checkAndSave() }
            }
            .hiddenIfKeyboardActive()
        }
    }
    
    var changeTypeMenu: some View {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.down").icon(15)
            .menuOnPress {
                Button(action: { self.manager.changeType(.text) } ) { Text("Text Response") }
                Button(action: { self.manager.changeType(.multiple) } ) { Text("Multiple Choice") }
                Button(action: { self.manager.changeType(.checkbox) } ) { Text("Checkbox") }
            }
    }
    
    var optionsSection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            HStack {
                Text("Options")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                ActionIcon("plus", size: 15) { manager.addOption() }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            ForEach(manager.options!, id: \.self) { opt in
                OptionCell(manager, option: opt)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func checkAndSave() {
        if manager.checkQuestion() {
            manager.saveQuestion()
            self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class QuestionManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var question: Question
    @Published var type: Question.QuestionType
    @Published var prompt: String
    @Published var options: [String]?
    @Published var error: String? = nil
    @Published var id = ""
    
    init(_ question: Question) {
        self.question = question
        self.type = question.type
        self.prompt = question.prompt
        self.options = question.options
        self.id = question.id
    }
    
    func saveQuestion() {
        self.question.prompt = prompt
        self.question.type = type
        self.question.options = options
    }
    
    func checkQuestion() -> Bool {
        if type == .checkbox || type == .multiple {
            if options!.count < 2 {
                error = "You must have at least two options"
                return false
            }
            else if options!.contains("") {
                error = "Options must not be empty"
                return false
            }
            else if !options!.elementsAreUnique() {
                error = "Options must be unique"
                return false
            }
        }
        if prompt.isEmpty {
            error = "You must include a prompt for your question"
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func changeType(_ type: Question.QuestionType) {
        if type == .text {
            options = nil
        }
        else {
            options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
        }
        self.type = type
    }
    
    func addOption() {
        guard options != nil else { return }
        if options!.count == 5 {
            error = "No more than 5 options are permitted"
        }
        else {
            let count = options!.count
            let newOption = "Option \(count + 1)"
            options!.append(newOption)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteOption(option: String) {
        guard options != nil else { return }
        guard let index = self.options!.firstIndex(of: option) else {
            self.error = "An error occured during deleting ... sorry you're screwed"
            return
        }
        self.options!.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to include a [mre]. No one can reproduce your code since it includes a bunch of custom types. Try to pare it down to what is necessary to show the problem in a way that others can test.

Comment: You may also find that making a minimum reproducible example will lead you to your own answer.

Comment: @jnpdx and Yrb. You guys were absolutely correct. Turns out MyCustomTextField in the OptionCell already had its own onTapGesture modifier. I was reluctant at first to try to strip away the fluff from the problem, but it was exactly what I needed to do. Thanks guys, I'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You can either add your own answer if you feel like it would benefit others, or otherwise consider removing the question.